# A simple question about a limit

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following data:

1) $u(t),u′(t)$ and $u′′(t)$ are bounded

2) $u''(t)+cu'(t)+f(u(t))=0$ where $c>0$ and $f$ is continuous

3) $\int_{0}^{+\infty}{u'(t)^2}<\infty$

I want to prove that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}{u'(t)}=0$$ but I don't know why...

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is this related to your two earlier, similar questions about this kind of equation?

Comment: Yes it is... =D

Comment: In fact, I can't understand the 'sketchy proof' of one of my questions about this.

Comment: If it's related to your other questions, then 1) you should include a link to those other questions, and 2) you should indicate what it is about the other messages that you don't understand, so people don't have to start from scratch. Indeed, maybe the best thing is not to ask a new question at all, but just to ask for more details at one of the old questions.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the help

Comment: Solved? Where? If you mean that you have solved it, you can post your solution here and then, later, accept it --- that's encouraged at this website.

Comment: Oh, the answer was here and it was erased. The 'sketchy' solution is: 'if the limit do not exist, then the integral is divergent. So the limit exists. And if the limit is not 0, then once again by the integral, this one is divergent, what is a contradiction.'

Comment: Raphael, if you are referring to the answer posted by DoctorBatmanGod, an objection was raised by @Matematicos Chibchas in the comments, and then DBG deleted the answer. So maybe the problem isn't solved.